# Recursive looping on a set of dictionaries on Python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I'm trying to loop a set of dictionaries that contain subsequent values to each other to make one large dictionary.
There's basically a dictionary in which there are lists (that contain dictionaries) and these lists are spread across different dictionaries that contain lists of dictionaries.

It's probably pretty confusing, so below you'll find an example of of the dictionaries I made:

```
datapage1 = {"events":{"data":[{"A":{"1_2": "2",
                                  "1_3":{"data":[{"a_ORIGINAL":"1"},
                                                   {"a_ORIGINAL":"2"},
                                                   {"a_ORIGINAL":"3"}],
                                           "sub_dir":{"location":"datapage11b"}},
                                  "1_4":"4",
                                  "1_5":"5",
                                  "1_6":"6",}},
                         {"B":"2_1"},
                         {"C":"3_1"},
                         {"D":"4_1"},
                         {"E":"5_1"}],
                 "sub_dir":{"location":"datapage2"}} }


datapage2 = {"data":[{"F" : "FROMdata2"},
                {"G":"FROMdata2"},
                {"H":"FROMdata2"},
                {"I":"FROMdata2"},
                {"J":"FROMdata2"}],
        "sub_dir":{"location": "datapage3"}}


datapage3 = {"data":[{"K":"FROMdata3"},
                {"L":"FROMdata3"},
                {"M":{"FROMdata3": "1",
                                  "13_2":{"data":[{"data3_ORIGINAL":"1"},
                                                   {"data3_ORIGINAL":"2"},
                                                   {"data3_ORIGINAL":"3"}],
                                           "sub_dir":{"location":"datapage33b"}},
                                  "13_3":"3",
                                  "13_4":"4",
                                  "13_5":"5",}},
                {"N":"FROMdata3"},
                {"O":"FROMdata3"}],
        "sub_dir":{"nolocation": "None"}}

datapage11b = {"data":[{"FROMdata11b SUB_ADDED":"4"},
                   {"FROMdata11b SUB_ADDED":"5"},
                   {"FROMdata11b SUB_ADDED":"6"}],
           "sub_dir":{"location":"datapage11c"}} 

datapage11c = {"data":[{"FROMdata11c SUB_ADDED":"7"},
                   {"FROMdata11c SUB_ADDED":"8"},
                   {"FROMdata11c SUB_ADDED":"9"}],
           "sub_dir":{"location":"datapage33b"}}

datapage33b = {"data":[{"FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED":"4"},
                   {"FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED":"5"},
                   {"FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED":"6"}],
           "sub_dir":{"location":"datapage44c"}}

datapage44c = {"data":[{"FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED":"1"},
                   {"FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED":"2"},
                   {"FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED":"3"}],
           "sub_dir":{"nolocation":"None"}}
```

Basically each dictionary has a *data*-key which contains a list. This *data-list* is continued in another dictionary within a *data*-key.

The *sub_dir* -key points to the right dictionary if the list is to be continued.

I've compiled a recursive loop by looking at other solutions on this site, and it sort of works, but not completely. 
Here's my loop:

```
def findSubDict(v, prefix=''):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
         for k, v2 in v.items():
             if k == 'location':
                 borrow_dir = v2
                 upOne = prefix.replace("sub_dir", "data")
                 for item in eval(borrow_dir + "['data']"):
                     eval("datapage1" + upOne + ".append(item)")
                 while "location" in eval(borrow_dir + "['sub_dir']"):
                     borrow_dir = eval(borrow_dir + "['sub_dir']['location']")
                     for item in  eval(borrow_dir + "['data']"):
                         eval("datapage1" + upOne + ".append(item)")
             p2 = "{}['{}']".format(prefix, k)
             findSubDict(v2, p2)

    elif isinstance(v, list):
        for i, v2 in enumerate(v):
            p2 = "{}[{}]".format(prefix, i)
            findSubDict(v2, p2)

findSubDict(datapage1)
pprint.pprint(datapage1)
```

When I try running it, the results aren't consistent. For example, I get pretty much the following result, but when I tried it multiple times I noticed that the sometimes some of the keys and values within `events['data'][12]['13_2']['data']` are missing they should be.

*(I highlighted the missing keys&values in the output with "----->")*

```
{'events': {'data': [{'A': {'1_2': '2',
                            '1_3': {'data': [{'a_ORIGINAL': '1'},
                                             {'a_ORIGINAL': '2'},
                                             {'a_ORIGINAL': '3'},
                                             {'FROMdata11b SUB_ADDED': '4'},
                                             {'FROMdata11b SUB_ADDED': '5'},
                                             {'FROMdata11b SUB_ADDED': '6'},
                                             {'FROMdata11c SUB_ADDED': '7'},
                                             {'FROMdata11c SUB_ADDED': '8'},
                                             {'FROMdata11c SUB_ADDED': '9'},
                                             {'FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED': '4'},
                                             {'FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED': '5'},
                                             {'FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED': '6'},
                                             {'FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED': '1'},
                                             {'FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED': '2'},
                                             {'FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED': '3'}],
                                    'sub_dir': {'location': 'datapage11b'}},
                            '1_4': '4',
                            '1_5': '5',
                            '1_6': '6'}},
                     {'B': '2_1'},
                     {'C': '3_1'},
                     {'D': '4_1'},
                     {'E': '5_1'},
                     {'F': 'FROMdata2'},
                     {'G': 'FROMdata2'},
                     {'H': 'FROMdata2'},
                     {'I': 'FROMdata2'},
                     {'J': 'FROMdata2'},
                     {'K': 'FROMdata3'},
                     {'L': 'FROMdata3'},
                     {'M': {'13_2': {'data': [{'data3_ORIGINAL': '1'},
                                              {'data3_ORIGINAL': '2'},
                                              {'data3_ORIGINAL': '3'},
                                       -----> {'FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED': '4'},
                                       -----> {'FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED': '5'},
                                       -----> {'FROMdata33b SUB_ADDED': '6'},
                                       -----> {'FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED': '1'},
                                       -----> {'FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED': '2'},
                                       -----> {'FROMdata44c SUB_ADDED': '3'}],
                                     'sub_dir': {'location': 'datapage33b'}},
                            '13_3': '3',
                            '13_4': '4',
                            '13_5': '5',
                            'FROMdata3': '1'}},
                     {'N': 'FROMdata3'},
                     {'O': 'FROMdata3'}],
            'sub_dir': {'location': 'datapage2'}}}
```

So, my questions is: "**Why is this happening?**" 
Probably needless to mention, but my goal (of course) is to get all the keys and values.
I've been checking my code over and over again, and just can't figure it out...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Happy holidays to everyone! :)

Comment: I'm confused.  What exactly are you trying to do? those calls to `eval` are a red flag

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be... :D
I'll make an EDIT and try to be more clear. 
But basically I want to loop the first dictionary (datapage1) and add values from other dictionaries to the appointed places. There's a "sub_dir/location" info which points to another dictionary that has some more values. This sub_dir/location -dict may continue onwards to another dict that contains even more values. All of these values should be appended to the datapage1-dict, to the appropriate location.
Therefore the recursive loop to go through datapage1 and to append these sub_dir's...

Comment: P.S. I'm using `eval` just because I don't know any other way of using the `[sub_dir][location]`-value as a dictionary location...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests and on one of them I find myself modifying the original dictionnaries... and fell like you in inconsistencies because the same dict may be used more than one time for example datapage33b and datapage44c.

So I decided to work on copies and got consistent results with the following code which simply does not keep the `sub_dir` parts once processed:

```
def process(dic):
    cr = None
    if not isinstance(dic, dict):
        return dic
    if 'data' in dic:
        cr = {'data': [ process(d) for d in dic['data'] ] }
    else:
        cr = { k: process(dic[k]) for k in dic }
    try:
        temp = process(eval(dic['sub_dir']['location']))['data']
        cr['data'].extend(temp)
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return cr
```

But **beware**: like your original code, this one uses `eval` meaning that you should never use it on uncontrolled input

Comment: **This worked perfectly! Thank you so much @SergeBallesta!! **
...but I'm still slightly confused. So it was the modifying of the original dict that caused the inconsistencies?
Also, thanks for the heads up with `eval`. I've noticed that `eval` isn't the preferred method to use, but is there any other way to pass a value as dict key? 

I spent the whole last weekend looking for a solution, but this was the only one that worked?